# Using leaflet to produce plot with total count

Tags: r, plot, leaflet, interactive

I am trying to use the leaflet package in R to produce an interactive visual which helps me visualize the following data:

```
      Provice      Lat     Long     Date Confirmed Recovered Deaths
1       Anhui 31.82570 117.2264 20-01-22         1         0      0
2       Anhui 31.82570 117.2264 20-01-23         9         0      0
3       Anhui 31.82570 117.2264 20-01-24        15         0      0
4       Anhui 31.82570 117.2264 20-01-25        39         0      0
5       Anhui 31.82570 117.2264 20-01-26        60         0      0
6       Anhui 31.82570 117.2264 20-01-27        70         0      0
7       Anhui 31.82570 117.2264 20-01-28       106         0      0
8       Anhui 31.82570 117.2264 20-01-29       152         2      0
9       Anhui 31.82570 117.2264 20-01-30       200         2      0
10      Anhui 31.82570 117.2264 20-01-31       237         3      0
```

Note: There are 10 Provices in total each with their respective coordinates.

So far I have been able to create the following image:
[image]

using the following code:

```
dta2 %>% 
  leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
  addMarkers(label = dta2$Confirmed  , lng = dta2$Long, lat = dta2$Lat ,clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(), popup = ~paste("Provice:", dta2$Provice))
```

However, my goal is to display the total number of confirmed cases for this virus at each cluster as opposed to the number of observations for each cluster (there are 22 obs for each province). In other words, I would like to display the sum of the confirmed column for each of the 10 provinces in their individual clusters as opposed to a frequency.  Can anybody please shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Do you absolutely want to use clusters? I think you should just combine the data by province (summing over every days) and display the result on your map. If that's good for you, I'll help you with it.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Sorry I a new to leafplot and am doing this as a side project to get experience in it. I assume I would make a second dataset that summarizes my data by province (sum confirmed cases). Would the code be the same as above?

Comment: I'll write you down an official answer, give me 5 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to be sure my proposition works fine since I don't have access to your data. But I think the following might work. Please note that I'm using the `data.table` package to summarize the data, you will need to install it if you don't already have it.

```
library(data.table)

# Summarize the data
setDT(dta2)
dta2 <- dta2[, .(
  Confirmed = sum(Confirmed),
  Recovered = sum(Recovered),
  Deaths = sum(Deaths)
), .(Provice, Lat, Long)]

# Create the leaflet map
leaflet(dta2) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(
    lng = ~Long,
    lat = ~Lat,
    label = ~Confirmed,
    labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE)
  )
```

You can customize the display with the argument `labelOptions` of the `addLabelOnlyMarkers()` function if you want.

Comment: This code shows the locations of the provinces, but does not display the sums. How could I modify this code so that it shows the sums of confirmed cases?

Comment: If you write `dta2[]` after having summarize the data, can you see the total number of confirmed cases by province in the `Confirmed` column?

Comment: Yes, the first half of the code works perfectly. I can see the summarized data for all 10 provinces. I am just not able to display this summed value on the leaflet plot. I have the pins displayed on the plot, but there aren't any numeric values and if I click on them or hover over them nothing appears. Any thoughts?

Comment: I just made an edit, adding the `labelOptions` argument. Is it improving something?

Comment: Sir, you are amazing. Thank you so much for your help! This works. I would like to modify the appearance of the boxes where the numbers are, but I think I can manage that with a google search :)

Comment: Pleasure @Jose, and yes, you will be able to modify the appearance by modifying the `labelOptions` argument. Juste make sure to keep the `noHide=TRUE` to make sure the labels actually appear on the map.